# Sphinx latex output filename

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx

When running `sphinx-build -b latex ...` Sphinx writes a `*.tex` file into some output directory. The name of that `*.tex` file seems to somehow be derived from the `project` title set in `conf.py`.

I'd like to integrate the Sphinx Latex generation into my build system. For the dependency management I need to know the exact name of the generated `*.tex` file.

Is there any way to determine the name of the generated file without hard-coding that name into the build system? Or is there a way to set this name manually (without changing the `project` variable)?

Comment: You can use `ls`, `find` or `glob` (or your build system's OS equivalent) to find that file

Comment: But that's only after the build has already run. I need to know it before, during the configure phase (CMake). Also, there may be multiple `*.tex` files in the output directory.

Comment: You can use the `latex_documents` configuration variable to set the name of the *.tex file: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_documents

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by mzjn and explained in the [Sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-latex_documents), one can set the name of the `*.tex` and `*.pdf` files via the `latex_documents` option in `conf.py`.

The canonical use case is probably to add the following at the end of `conf.py`.

```py
#...
latex_documents = [('index', 'doc.tex', project, author, 'manual')]
```

This eventually produces a file `doc.pdf`.

Comment: For `rst2pdf` it's similar: `pdf_documents = [("index", "outfilename", "title", author)]`